# How to pass NTLM credentials to zuul request header

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, ntlm, netflix-zuul

I have a Windows service "A" being used for authentication purposes (NOT managed by us) and I have Spring-boot based REST Api service "B" (managed by us) which uses Zuul to route traffic. There is an external service "C" (NOT managed by us) that needs to talk to the Windows service through our REST Apis. Since "A" uses NTLM authentication we need to pass the request body from "C" and add the ntlm credentials in the headers at "B" and route the traffic using zuul.

My question is, how do I add NTLM credentials in Java to the routed traffic in zuul headers?

~ Jatin

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own [ZuulFilter](http://netflix.github.io/zuul/javadoc/zuul-core/com/netflix/zuul/ZuulFilter.html).

Something along the lines of

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext;
import com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter;

public class MyFilter extends ZuulFilter {

  @Override
  public String filterType() {
    return "pre";
  }

  @Override
  public int filterOrder() {
    return 1;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

    // now add your headers to the request

    return null;
  }

}
```

In your app just make sure the filter bean is created and it will be automatically registered:

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public MyFilter myFilter() {
    return new MyFilter();
  }

}
```

Have a look at [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Zuul will work fine with Spring Session. There are many blogs about this.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot.html